# Unable to login to roundcube using system user account and other issues

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, roundcube

I am newbie in server admin, and facing a few issues here.

We have a ubuntu 12.04 server setup with AWS EC2. We have installed postfix and roundcube and added two users to the system named "info" and "noreply"

Once the roundcube is installed, when i try to login I am getting the message "Connect to IMAP Server failed"

I am not sure what is the issue and this can be resolved. Also when i add a new user in the system using "adduser" command, how this user can be added to the roundcube database?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, for I have not used AWS yet, but it seems like you have no IMAP server running (duh!). For you could have guessed it by the error message, I'll try to explain it the best I can.

In general a Mail-Server will consist of several parts

- The Mail Transfer Agent (MTA) which is responsible for transferring Mails (usually between different servers)
- A Mail Delivery Agent (MDA) which transports mails to local directories
- A retrieval Service (usually some sort of IMAP or POP3 server)
- The backend (LDAP, MySQL, whatever you'd like to have)
- A frontend (optional, can be replaced by a Mail Retrieval Agent (MRA) or an Mail User Agent (MUA))

No I am not quite sure about your setup, for you provided too little information, but I think you'd at least lack the third part. You'll have to install some kind of Deamon that offers you access to the Mailboxes via IMAP. In your setup Dovecot could be useful, which already comes with an MDA, which can be very comfortable. There are some tutorials around about how to set up postfix with MySQL and Dovecot. Then you'll only have to set up the correct server address in Roundcube and you'll be nearly done (postfixadmin could be useful, too, for it provides an ugly bt effective Web UI to manage domains, users, etc.).

---

Please see:
https://library.linode.com/email/postfix/postfix2.9.6-dovecot2.0.19-mysql